# Pulling Selected Dropdown Menu Item in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

The dropdown menu looks something like this:

```
<option label="John Smith" value="string:0012">John Smith</option>
<option label="John Doe" value="string:0001" selected="selected">John Doe</option>
```

Here is some code I am using:

```
    try:
        SelectedUser = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="some-content"]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/select').get_attribute("value");
        print(SelectedUser)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        SelectedUser= "Not Available"
```

By using get_attribute("value") I am returning "string:0001" which makes sense, because it is the value of the selected item.  But what I am trying to return is the label value of "John Doe".

So I tried this code:

```
    try:
        SelectedUser = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="some-content"]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/select').get_attribute("label");
        print(SelectedUser)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        SelectedUser= "Not Available"
```

This returns the value of "None".  How to I have Selenium get the the proper text?

Comment: Post the URL to have a look.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a public link.

Comment: Make sure the XPath you've written has only one match.

Comment: Did you try `SelectedUser = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="some-content"]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/select').text;`

Comment: ```SelectedUser = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="some-content"]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/select').text;```

This returns the full list of users in the dropdown.

Comment: Being that I can pull the data for value but no other elements, I think the correct approach might be to just get the attribute for outerHTML and parse it with BeautifulSoup.